# Firebase query search

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just want to get user post by user email in all of posts. How can I get user email? If I have to change my query let me know.

Here is my code

```
  const getUserPosts = db
    .collection('posts')
    .doc()
    .collection('posts')
    .where('email', '==', user.email)
    .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc');
```

`

[image]

[image]

this is my Firebase posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get documents from the sub-collection ("posts") only or event from the root level collection ("posts")? If former, then consider changing it's name else collection group query will fetch documents from root collection as well.

Then try this query:

```js
const query = firebase.firestore().collectionGroup("posts").where('email', '==', user.email).orderBy("timestamp", "desc")

query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  const postsData = querySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data())
  console.log(postsData)
})
```

Comment: I don't know why I got empty array. I changed posts name.

Comment: Can you please share a [gist](https://gist.github.com) of updated code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Honggilseong/fc6bbe11690682b611c4bdb6809b16d2 here is my gist thank you for answering

Comment: @icdeverything looks like you are missing set state part... `setPosts(postsData)` after fetching the data and logging it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a collection group query to get posts from all "posts" collections. Have you tried that?

Comment: That looks correct, is the sdk version up-to-date?

Comment: By the way, you will need to manually create a collection group index for this to work.

Comment: getUserPosts.get().then(post =>
        post.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.data());
        }),
      );
console.log >>>> null
Yes I did